# Is there a way to get the form data that is submitted to the server, before on the client-side javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have an HTML form

```
form(method="post)
    input(name="field")
    button submit
```

upon submitting it on the server I receive the form data as an object

```
app.post('/', function(req){
    console.log(req.body);
    // => {field: 'value'}
});
```

Is there a way to access this object on the client-side javascript before submitting the form?

```
form(method="post submit="submit(this)")
```

```
function submit(){
    this.data? //
    // =?> Something that gives the same object 
    // {field:value}
}
```

I've searched and found various ways but they only deal with finding the particular fields and elements and extracting the values from them.

[`document.getElementById("...").value`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979319/1266650) - not what I want.

[`oText = oForm.elements["text_element_name"];`](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-form.phtml) - not what I want

What I want is the "composed" object that gets sent to the server via POST request.

Comment: Please explain the downvote..

Comment: I didn't vote down but maybe if you explain what your intention are, then they could give you a better answer

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but there's obviously many answers on the web and in stackoverflow for this question you're asking. I'd recommend you to spend some time looking for them before asking.

Comment: You've encountered what I feel is a significant flaw in SO. People can downvote and not be identified or have to give a reason. Frankly I don't understand why SO allows this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery you can use the `serializeArray` method.

```
$('#myForm').serializeArray();
```

Will give you an array like this:

```
[
  {
     name:  'inputField1',
     value: 'my value'
  },
  ...
]
```

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/